# db connection path to connect application that is running in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, robo3t

I am running nodejs application in docker. In that application I am trying to connect my system database. But  It is not working

In my environment file:

```
**MONGODB_URI=mongodb://192.168.1.174:27017/sampleDB**
SESSION_SECRET=sample
App_PORT = 8088
```

But I am getting error and unable to access the db.

My application is running on docker machine ip **192.168.99.100:8088**

Here, I attached my docker running command statement: 
[image]
How to connect my system db into that application

Comment: I guess 192.168.1.174 is the IP address of your host. Are you sure mongo is listening on all interfaces and not only on localhost?

Comment: Yes. If I give mongodb path as localhost or any other ip like 192.168.1.88 ip also it is connecting to that ip address

Comment: Normally that nodejs is running sucessfully in localhost and using 192.68.1.174 db (other system db). When I try to run this db path in docker i am not getting

Comment: In your host (where mongodb is running), try running `netstat -ntpl | grep 27017`

Comment: where should I execute an above command

Comment: Wait, what OS do you have in your host?

Comment: Wait, what OS do you have in your host? windows 8

Comment: Ok, I am unable to help you then, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The IP depends how the containers are run. If using `docker-compose`, it creates a network for you in which containers are accessible to themselves using service name (eg. `db` should you use it). If not, and you did not specify any network, the default `bridge` network is used (called `docker0` on your docker machine).

Since you are running containers separately (using `docker run`), you have to either give specific IP address to the container (you can get one from inside the container using `docker exec container_name ip a`) or connect to it via the gateway (your docker machine). However, in order to do that, the database port has to be exposed (eg. `27017:27017` when running).

I recommend you start using `docker-compose` from now on, many things will get easier when running a stack of linked containers.

Comment: I am running my container using docker run -d 8088:8088 nitikishu/samplenodejs.. application is running on that docker machine default ip address 192.168.99.100:8088 from this link my application is running. But I can not able to login to the application system. In my application I try to connect  another system database that system ip 192.168.1.174 . It is not connecting to that sytem

Comment: That's a different network so it looks like a firewall issue inside the docker machine. Like I said, start using `docker-compose` or create a docker network and make these containers join that network. Or start using Linux, Docker on Windows sucks like hell.

Comment: But If I run the nodejs application in my localhost:8088 it will run and connecting with others system db(192.168.1.174). Samething I am trying to do it in docker. It is not happening. I have built image for the application with environment variable :mongodb-uri=monogdb://192.168.1.174:27017/sampleDB port 8088. when I run the image in docker like docker run -d 8088:8088 nitikishu/samplenodejs i am getting error like as I shared in screenshot image. Docker machine ip 192.168.99.100:8088 from this url only that image is running. it is not running in my localhost after pulling and run in docker